# Xamarin Android setting text value of EditText not working

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm working on my first Xamarin Android app and I'm creating an Activity which has dynamically added editText views (as I'm getting the list of fields from the database).

All is working as expected except that I'm setting the .text value of the editText and it's not being displayed!

My activity has a single LinearLayout in it and then in OnCreate I'm creating a new editText view and then adding it to the LinearLayout. The field appears but it is empty:

```
        var etEmail = new EditText(linUserDetails.Context);
        etEmail.SetText(lru.email, EditText.BufferType.Editable  );
        etEmail.Text = lru.email;
        etEmail.SetSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        linUserDetails.AddView(etEmail, etLayoutParams);
```

The editText appears in the expected place but it is empty (lru is the object with my data in it and lru.email does have a valid email address in it). I can set the hint and it appears but for some reason the text will not display!

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Maybe try set text after addView

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't make any difference - the editText is still empty! Thanks.

Comment: If the color of text is same as the color of the text background, you won't see the text, is right? Please check the color. Or you need complete the code you have posted.

Comment: The background is white and the text is black and when I type something into the editText I can see it. It's just that it doesn't have the value I set in code when the activity loads. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I am late, have you solved it? I have test most times, there is one time it is same as yours. Because, in the `.axml` file, I put a `EditText`, and it's height is full screen, and then I add another `EditText` in code, so I think it is the `EditText`-code in the screen. I know you have describe your problem in detail, but we need to see you code, and then we can find the error where it is, is it right? By the way, your code you have provided works well. `etLayoutParams` can't be seen here.

Comment: I think I have resolved it. The linUserDetails is a LinearLayout which itself will be added to a CardView. When I added the LinearLayout to the CardView, I was using the wrong context and although the EditText was added it seemed to lose it's text value!